# Errors while installing ROOT

Tags: python, miniconda

I'm new to Python. I installed miniconda to get packages iminuit and minuit.  To do this, I created a new environment to avoid conflicts. But when I try to install minuit with the command

```
conda install minuit -c conda-forge
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from      current channels:

 - minuit

Current channels:

 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
 - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package     you're
looking for, navigate to

 https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the messages say, the package isn't available in the current channels. If you look on anaconda.org you will find:

https://anaconda.org/mutirri/minuit which says:

> To install this package with conda run one of the following: 
> `conda install -c mutirri minuit`
>  `conda install -c mutirri/label/all minuit`

Comment: I tried with these, but I get the same messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the versioning of CERN's ROOT packages, but I guess that they no longer support Minuit package, instead Imminuit which [is more lightweight and Jupyter friendly](https://pypi.org/project/iminuit/).

So you can install this package with this command, according to [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/iminuit):

`conda install -c anaconda iminuit`

Comment: It seems that everything is gone good. So, does iminuit support all root packages?

Comment: I'm not really sure If it supports all the ROOT packages, but according to its description it says:

"iminuit is a Jupyter-friendly Python interface for the Minuit2 C++ library maintained by CERN’s ROOT team. It can be used as a general robust function minimisation method, but is most commonly used for likelihood fits of models to data, and to get model parameter error estimates from likelihood profile analysis."

So maybe, it's one of the ROOT's packages? But I can guarantee that it's the same package used by ROOT, in Python.

Comment: Can I ask for which goal do you desire to use Iminuit? Maybe we can find a solution together, specifically to your need.

Comment: I need It to implement a minimisation method; so it seems to be the right package. Thank you!

Comment: Yay! I agree with you. I guess that's what this package is made for! :)